# What is the metal brace on this rubber hose? How important is it?

Tags: honda, power-steering, crv, hose

I'm replacing a rubber return power steering hose on my 2004 Honda CRV. I noticed the old one had some kind of metal brace on it. Is this just so it retains the curved shape? The replacement hose I bought is just a power steering hose from AutoZone.

Pictured is part 53733-S9A-003, the "oil tank hose":
[image: 53733-S9A-003]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly what it's for, but usually they'd put these in there for one of two reasons.

1. They need a hard place to mount the hose so what's holding on to it doesn't wear on it.
2. They are putting two pieces together for some stupid reason.

I'm thinking it may be the first reason, but who knows why Honda does anything.

As for your replacement hose ... if it's just regular hose, make sure there's no kinks or binding in it anywhere or the fluid will not flow correctly back to the reservoir, which will affect how the power steering works. Also make sure it isn't touching on any metal edges, like body panels. This will wear holes in it.

Comment: There could also be a valve or restrictor fitted at that point...

Comment: It looks like it is the second reason.  Here is a picture of an article from another manufacturer of the same part number which does not have a crimp sleeve there.  http://www.autoparts100.com/53733s9a003-crv-steering-hose-normal-quality-p-185020.html

Comment: A number of similarish-looking parts without photos have diagrams showing both sleeves and what appear to be matching mounting points, e.g. http://www.autoparts100.com/53713swaa02-crv-steering-hose-normal-quality-p-184989.html